# Issues using Max function and orderby in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake and I am trying to run some sql query that pulls out the latest date and its related ip

table name: lex

| id | date | ip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2022-01-14 15:03:43.000 | 5.3.3.46.173 |
| 001 | 2021-01-14 15:03:43.000 | 9.3.3.26.193 |
| 002 | 2022-01-14 15:03:43.000 | null |
| 001 | 2021-01-13 15:03:43.000 | 4.3.9.46.173 |
| 002 | 2022-01-10 15:03:43.000 | 8.1.3.26.122 |
| 003 | 2022-01-14 15:03:43.000 | 7.3.3.66.177 |

what I am trying to achieve

| id | date | ip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2022-01-14 15:03:43.000 | 5.3.3.46.173 |
| 002 | 2022-01-14 15:03:43.000 | null |
| 003 | 2022-01-14 15:03:43.000 | 7.3.3.66.177 |

what I did so far

```
Select id,
       date,
       ip
From lex
where date = (Select Max(date) from lex)
```

This code only gives me one row instead of three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `QUALIFY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM lex
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) = 1;
```

If it is possible to have more than one row per id at the exact same time the `RANK` should be used instead.

Comment: You are the best!! please train me or refer me to materials I can study. Between please can you explain what this code does. thanks

Comment: Snowflake Data Cloud is a really rich platform.  Two places to start: https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/ and https://community.snowflake.com/s/snowflake-university

Answer (score 0):

I thought "most recent" is defined by the date-column, but that's not true. "Most recent" is in your case defined on the row order, isn't it? For example for ID 001 the date-column is the same for the first two records and you just pick the first occurence.

If that's the case, it cannot be solved in a deterministic way with SQL based on above input table. A result set will be retrieved and result sets have no order (unless order by is applied).

My recommendation: Add a new SQL column, which is showing the exact insert date timestamp and from then it can be solved.

Lets say the value is a typo, then please try:

```
select * from lex a
where date = (select max(date) from lex b where a.ip = b.ip)
```

Comment: please this code did not give me what I want

Comment: Sorry. I didnt get the question correctly, but luckily Lukasz solved it.