# Difficulties trying to replace null values with values from previous row in snowflake using sql

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Please I have a table, with null values and I am trying to write an sql query to  replace them with values from the previous row

table: customer

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 34 |
| 002 | Null |
| 003 | Null |
| 004 | Null |
| 005 | 20 |
| 006 | Null |
| 007 | Null |
| 008 | 55 |

what I want to achieve

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 34 |
| 002 | 20 |
| 003 | 20 |
| 004 | 20 |
| 005 | 20 |
| 006 | 55 |
| 007 | 55 |
| 008 | 55 |

thanks

Comment: in relational databases there is no inherent notion of *previous row* unless the table is sorted somehow. So how do you define the *previous row*?

Comment: lets assume the table is sorted in descending order, I will update it now

Answer (score 4):

Using [`LAG`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lag.html) with `IGNORE NULLS`

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(value, LAG(value) IGNORE NULLS OVER(ORDER BY id)) AS value
FROM customer
ORDER BY id;
```

LAG(previous)/LEAD(following) value

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=afe17f8912ae888026c0303278d504fe)**

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the contribution, please can you help look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71111997/issues-using-max-function-and-orderby-in-snowflake/71112152#71112152

Comment: MySQL is far behind other RDBMS, didn't even know this existed. +1

Comment: @Lukasz, please this didnt seem to work properly especially for the once with 3 NULL values above them

Comment: @lee Please find attached demo. Here you could use LEAD or LAG but ORDER BY has to be DESC. If this operation has to be done per specific group then `OVER(PARTION BY ... ORDER BY id)`

Answer (score 0):

A subquery to get the values from the immediate following row where `value is not null` should do the job:

```
select id,
(select value from customer where id >= c.id and value is not null
order by id limit 1) as value
from customer c
order by id
```